# How to create BitLocker protected DVD disks?

Tags: encryption, dvd, bitlocker, disk-encryption, cd

I am planning to copy my personal data on CD or DVD disks for archival reasons. But I don't want anyone who has the disk to access my data.

So how can I create CD/DVD drives that are read-only and  encrypted?

I am thinking of two methods.

1. Create VHD files > Put data in it > Encrypt it with BitLocker > Burn *.vhd file to DVD
2. Burn data to DVD > Encrypt the whole disk directly (if possible)

Any ideas on how should it be done? Is there some kind of risk (of error or corruption or, data loss)?

Any advice or information would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi - depending on which dvd burning software you use, it is possible to encrypt the media during the actual burning process. Another approach i have seen working is to zip your data and encrypt the resulting zip archives finally burning those archives onto the dvd media.

Comment: #2 isn't possible.  The way Bitlocker works is it rewrites the data that exists  on the disk.  This wouldn't be possible on a CD or DVD for obvious reasons.  #1 is doable because you can mount the VHD, encrypt the VHD, then unmount the VHD and write that to a disk.

Comment: @Jim Nielsen, can you please suggest such dvd burning software that encrypts data during the burning process? And will it work like BitLocker (on-the-fly decryption)?

Comment: I use Roxio Secure Burn whenever I need to create protected backup media - works a treat for me. More info here > https://support.corel.com/hc/en-us/articles/216117208-Roxio-Secure-Burn-Frequently-Asked-Questions